# JavaFX8 bind a List<SimpleStringProperty> to a TableColumn for heavy customized table cell

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

i have a data model "Rule"
A Rule consists of 1-x String parts saved as a List and an boolean value weather the rule is active or not.

To show this in my UI i want to add a TableView with 2 Columns.
Column 1 should display the Rule Text as a whole, but heavily customized. In the cell i add a textfield for each rule part which then get binded to the StrinProperty (Thats why i need a List of String Properties.
The 2. column should display a checkbox to activate or deactivate the rule (this is no problem an works fine)

Before my rule Model had the boolean isActive flag i used a Listview which had the whole Rule model class as Object. I made my own ListCell implementation and overrode updateItem(Object item, boolean isEmpty) to customize the cell to look  like this:

[image]

I want the tablecell in column 1 to look exactly how the listcell in my listview looked.
Because ListCell and Tablecell both inherit from IndexedCell i saw no problem in my way of changing the visual of the cell.

My problem is to bind the new datamodel to the table:

```
private TableView<Rule> tvRules;
this.tvRules = new TableView<Rule>();
this.tvRules.setPrefSize(GuiCore.prefWidth * 0.32, GuiCore.prefHeight * 0.32);
this.tvRules.setEditable(true);

headerBoxLbl = new Label("Active"); 
headerBox = new CheckBox();
headerBoxLbl.setGraphic(headerBox);
headerBoxLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
headerBox.setOnAction(e -> this.changeAllActiveBoxes());

rulePartsColumn = new TableColumn<Rule, List<SimpleStringProperty>>("Rule");
rulePartsColumn.setCellFactory((callback) -> new RuleTableCell());
rulePartsColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getRulePartsProperty());
rulePartsColumn.setResizable(false);
rulePartsColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().multiply(0.8));

isActiveColumn = new TableColumn<Rule, Boolean>();
isActiveColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getIsActiveProperty());
isActiveColumn.setCellFactory(cellData -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());   
isActiveColumn.setResizable(false);
isActiveColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().multiply(0.2));
isActiveColumn.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
isActiveColumn.setGraphic(headerBoxLbl);

this.tvRules.getColumns().addAll(rulePartsColumn, isActiveColumn);
```

As you see i create 2 Columns with the TableDataType Rule, one with Boolean type and one with the List as Data type.
The problem ist that i dont get the binding of the rulePartsColumn to the rule Model to work:
[image: The error i get]

I really dont know how to bind this so in the cell i can work with a List of StringProperties (or SimpleStringProperties).

For reference my Model class Rule:

```
public class Rule {

private SimpleListProperty<SimpleStringProperty> ruleParts;
private SimpleBooleanProperty isActive;

public Rule() {
    this(true, Arrays.asList("", "=", ""));
}

public Rule(final boolean isActive, final List<String> ruleParts) {
    this.isActive = new SimpleBooleanProperty(isActive);
    this.ruleParts = new SimpleListProperty<SimpleStringProperty>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    for(int i = 0; i < ruleParts.size(); i++) {
        this.ruleParts.add(new SimpleStringProperty(ruleParts.get(i)));
    }
}

public SimpleListProperty<SimpleStringProperty> getRulePartsProperty() {
    return this.ruleParts;
}

public List<SimpleStringProperty> getRulePartsProperties() {
    return (List<SimpleStringProperty>)this.ruleParts;
}

public List<String> getRuleParts() {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < this.ruleParts.size(); i++) {
        parts.add(this.ruleParts.get(i).get());
    }

    return parts;
}

public SimpleBooleanProperty getIsActiveProperty() {
    return this.isActive;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive.get();
}

public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive.set(isActive);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `rulePartsColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<List<SimpleStringProperty>>(cellData.getValue().getRulePartsProperty()));` or simply `rulePartsColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rulePartsProperty"));`

Comment: So your first way is to encapsel the SimpleListString i get with cellData.getValue().getRulePartsProperty() in an extra SimpleObjectProperty? Why do i need to do this? The SimpleListProperty i get from my model is itsel a Property from javafx. And i dont need to do this with Stringproperties for example. And could you explain what you do in you second way or explain what the PropertyValueFactory you create there does with that parameter and why that should work?

Comment: `SimpleListProperty<T>` is a `Property<ObservableList<T>>` not a `Property<List<T>>` required for cell value factories of `TableColumn<*, List<T>>`. Since `SimpleListProperty<T>` does implement `List<T>` though, wrapping it inside a property works. The second alternative simply uses a class provided by JavaFX to do this instead of doing it yourself...

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. Do i even need the SimpleListProperty then in my model? Or for what do you even use this one then?

Comment: You use `ListProperty`s, if you need to replace a `ObservableList` wrapped in the property objec and still want the whole thing to be an implementation of `ObservableList` that delegates it's `get`/`set`/`size`/ect. methods to the wrapped value.